# Why isn't my system booting in UEFI mode?

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, uefi, gpt, usb-boot

I recently attempted to install Windows 10 as a dual boot alongside Ubuntu 14.04. I used WinUSB to create a bootable drive. I booted into the USB, but when I attempted to select the empty NTFS partition I created for Windows, I received the following error message: "Windows cannot install to this drive. The drive is of the GPT partition style." I know that Windows requires a GPT drive when the system boots in UEFI mode, so I've come to the conclusion that mine was not. However, when I disabled Legacy support in the BIOS menu, the USB with Windows on it disappeared from the boot menu. I know my motherboard, an ASUS M5A97 R.20, is UEFI-capable, so what is causing this problem?

Comment: Your firmware is UEFI-capable, but your bootable USB is not – WinUSB can only create BIOS-bootable USB disks. On Windows, Rufus or the official Microsoft's USB tool can create UEFI-capable ones. Someone else might know how to do that on Linux.

Comment: A similar question has been been answered at http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media.

Comment: That's odd considering that there's a folder in my USB called "efi".

Comment: I can't speak to WinUSB's capabilities, but more than an `EFI` directory is required to boot in EFI mode. Specifically, the filesystem must be FAT and the boot loader file itself must be present -- normally that's `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. There are many other things that could cause problems, too, some of them system-specific. Overall, I agree with grawity: You should try re-creating the USB drive with another tool, or at least check to see if the tool you use has options relating to EFI support.

Comment: I did using Rufus, worked like a charm. Thanks everyone!